# Find $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n})$

I know that $\{0\}$ is in the intersection because it lies between negative and positive numbers.

I want to show that for $x > 0$, $\exists n \in  \mathbb{N}$ such that $x > \frac{2}{n}$. By this logic, $x$ is outside of the interval and is thus not in the intersection. I'm confused by where "$x > 0$, $\exists n \in  \mathbb{N}$ such that $x > \frac{2}{n}$" comes from. I know that the Archimedean property states that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x > \frac{1}{n}$. But does this necessarily imply that $x$ is also greater than $\frac{2}{n}$?

For $x < 0$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x < -\frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow x > \frac{1}{n}$ which is basically what the Archimedean property states.

So $x = 0$ as desired.

Comment: Consider $\frac x2\gt \frac 1n$...

Comment: This looks like a follow-up question to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/992863/11994.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Archimedean property, $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y > \frac{1}{n}$.

In particular, given $x\in \mathbb{R}, x>0$, let $y=\frac{x}{2}$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y > \frac{1}{n}$, hence $x>\frac{2}{n}$.

Given $x\in \mathbb{R}, x<0$, let $y=-x$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y > \frac{1}{n}$, hence $x<-\frac{1}{n}$.